# How to hide links from users that aren't part of AD Group

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, active-directory-group

I am using VS 2013 and working on a MVC Web Application. It uses Windows Authentication. I wrote a bool method that checks for users in a specific AD group.

```
string user = User.Identity.Name;
PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "DOMAINNAME");
if(user.IsMemberOf(ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, "GroupName")){
    return true;
}
else
return false;
```

However, I am not able to use this method from my View since its not an extension method.

What I want to do is, check for user is in group and then hide the specific link if he/she isn't in that group.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Why not have a property in your model:

```
public bool IsAuthorized { get; set; }
```

In the controller, set the property in your action method before returning the model:

```
YourModel model = ...

string user = User.Identity.Name;
PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "DOMAINNAME");
model.IsAuthorized  = user.IsMemberOf(ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, "GroupName");

return View(model);
```

Then in the view, simply hide the link if it's not authorized

```
@if (model.IsAuthorized)
{
    @Html.Action(...) // or whatever your link is
}
```